# What data model to use for tables in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net-core, design-patterns, blazor

I am building a .Net 6 Blazor web app. I needs to display lots of html tables with data. For example I need tables that look like this:

```
       |Jul 17 | Jul 16  | Jul 15
--------------------------------- . . .
Hour 1 | 11.213 | 123.23 | 123.54
Hour 2 | 12.234 | 234.45 | 54.34
.
.
.
```

**Data:**

The data comes from an API in JSON format. Here is an example.

```
"prices": [
    {
        "period": {
            "start": "2022-07-01T23:00:00+01:00",
            "end": "2022-07-01T23:30:00+01:00"
        },
        "price": 245.00,
        "priceUp": 215.00,
        "priceDown": 215.00,
        "amount": 71.74
    },
```

**Code:**

I want to display a lot of tabular data and I would like to be able to compute new tabular data based on the ones I already have, like calculating averages of an existing "table" models rows.

I considered having a data structure like this:

```
public class DataTable
{
    public DataTable(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, decimal?>>? values)
    {
        Values = values ?? new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, decimal?>>();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, decimal?>>? Values { get; set; }
}
```

**Questions:**

- Is this a good approach?
- How can I store optional row and column headers?
- What if I want to create a table with strings? I can't restrict extension methods for a generic class to "number" types, so it seems to no be good design.

Comment: With no indication of where the data is coming from and what structure it has, I'm not sure anyone is going to try and answer your question.  You need to provide more detail.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the question with some details about data. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good is relative. I think this will work.

I would recommend doing Dictionary<string, string> instead of Dictionary<string, decimal?>. For optional headers you can just pass in a String.Empty. And it's simple enough to convert decimals to strings.